# issue with complex query involving returning 0 for no data in query result

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table defined in Oracle11g schema like this

```
Txn_summ_dec
=================
id 
currentdate
resource_id
user_id
trans_id
eventdescptn
```

each resource has different event descriptions.
I give a date range (of maximum 1 month or less) and resource_id and I want to get distinct count of all users for the given resource id, group by currentdate, eventdescptn

So I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(txn_summ_dec.user_id)) as dusers, currentDate, eventdescptn
FROM Txn_summ_dec
WHERE resource_id = 1
AND currentdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                    AND TO_DATE('2011-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY currentdate, eventdescptn
```

and it gives me rightly the result below

```
dusers   currentdate            eventdescptn 
182      12/01/2011 00:00:00    Save 
33       12/04/2011 00:00:00    Save 
98       12/01/2011 00:00:00    Read
22       12/30/2011 00:00:00    Write
```

I want result in the following format:
  From the query
with the given date range is suppose 5th to 5th of a month (or less) I want results for all dates in the range for all eventdescptn of a resource. **If there is no result for a particular date in the range, for a particular event descptn then it should still have that record in the resultset with a 'dusers' value = 0**

so if a resource has 3 different eventdescptns (Save, Read, Write) and the date range is 5th to 30th of a month then there should be a total of 26X3 = 78 records in the resultset..

How do I write a query for that? 
Also I will need to convert it to hibernate later.. but Sql to start with is fine
Thanks in advance

Comment: Labelling a stored `timestamp` column 'currentdate' is the _wrong_ thing to do - it should be labelled something like `event_occurred` (it's certainly not 'current' anymore).  You're going to want to create an `event` table that holds descriptions, and only store ids.  You're going to want to group by the **DAY** of the timestamp, not on something with (at minimum) second accuraccy.

Comment: sure, changing the name of the column is fine with me, it stores only date no time info..Also are you suggesting to use a temporary table event to get the result? if so how to do it?

Comment: No, not a temporary table, create a permanent `event` table, and only store ids in this summary table.  Also, are you _sure_ that your `currentdate` field is type date - you're including the time in your results - and you may want the time for logging purposes anyways.  Also, the reccommendation for range comparisons is minimum inclusive, maximum exclusive; so `AND currentDate >= TO_DATE('2011-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND currentDate < TO_DATE('2011-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` (guessing at oracle syntax here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the accepted answer here:
[generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

If I understand you correctly you don't necessarily have an event for every date in the range in your log.  That answer gives you a way to materialize a list of dates in the range.  If you can modify it to include 1 of each of those dates per event, you would just have to join back to the results you have already aggregated here and set the null dUsers to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I wonder if you could you do:

```
 WITH the_query AS (
      ... your query here ...
 )
 SELECT dusers, currentdate, eventdescptn 
   FROM the_query
  WHERE 0 != ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_query )
 UNION
 SELECT 0, NULL, NULL
   FROM the_query
  WHERE 0 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_query )
```

Comment: Given that the OP wants data for all dates (in the range), no (because you're giving a `null` date).  I'm fairly confident that the second half of the statement isn't going to return anything unless the original query returns **0** results.  Also, if it _did_ generate the 'missing' dates, you haven't given it any termination conditions - 'infinite' results.